# asp.net weird error creating a DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to create an account with the next code I've written in asp.net

But everytime when I create the datetime it's throwing me into the catch block, now I've used simple values like:

```
DateTime birthdate = new DateTime(1, 2, 2003);
```

but when I check the debugger, it's throwing me out of the try block at this line and I really don't understand why because Visual studio doesn't give me any errors so what can go wrong here???

```
try
{
    // male/female check
    string sex = "";
    if (rbMale.Checked)
    {
        sex = "Male";
    }
    else if (rbFemale.Checked)
    {
        sex = "Female";
    }
    // birthday
    int bdday = Convert.ToInt32(tbBdayDay.Value.ToString());
    int bdmonth = Convert.ToInt32(cbBdayMonth.Value.ToString());
    int bdyear = Convert.ToInt32(tbBdayYear.Value.ToString());

    //this line is pushing me into the catch block!! :(
    DateTime birthdate = new DateTime(1, 2, 2003);
    // username
    string name = tbFirstName.Value.ToString() + " " + tbLastName.Value.ToString();
    // fileshare link: www.filesharelink.com/+'username'+'random number'
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 10001);
    string filesharelink = "www.filesharelink.com/" + tbFirstName.Value.ToString() + randomNumber;
    // email
    string email = tbEmail.Value.ToString();
    // password
    string password = tbPassword1.Value.ToString();
    //returns true if account is succesfully registered
    if (administration.query.RegisterAccount(sex, birthdate, name, filesharelink, email, password))
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "titel", "alert('Account created succesfully, you can now log in!');", true);
    }
}
catch
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "titel", "alert('Error creating your account, please try again.');", true);
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio isn't giving you errors because you have a catch block that does not take an exception - It completely ignores what the error is.

Answer (score 5):

Arguments of `DateTime` constructor you're trying to use is `year`, `month`, `day`, but you're providing them in incorrect order.

So literally you're trying to create 2003 February of 0001 year in your code.

Answer (score 3):

```
new DateTime(1, 2, 2003);
```

Expects parameters in the format year, month day.

Your parameters are out of range.

Try using:

```
new DateTime(2003, 2, 1);
```

Assuming the month/day are the correct way around.